# oracle dbms sql question) case statement without subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, case

```
SELECT 
            CASE 
            TO_CHAR(last_day(SYSDATE),'DAY') 
                    WHEN '1' THEN last_day(SYSDATE) - 1 
                    WHEN '7' THEN last_day(SYSDATE) - 2 
                ELSE last_day(SYSDATE) 
            END 
    AS "Last legal business day" 
FROM 
    dual;
```

I want to deduplicate "a last_day(SYSDATE)" without using subquery.
just use only case statement.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question.  You could declare a local variable, assign `last_day(sysdate)` to that local variable and then use that local variable in your query.  I'm guessing that "without using subquery" means that you don't want to define a CTE that you reference.  But I'm not sure what problem using a CTE creates for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is not going to work as `TO_CHAR(value, 'DAY')` will output, for example, `"MONDAY   "` rather than a numeric value.

It will also not give consistent results in different countries as, depending on the `NLS_TERRITORY` parameter being used, different countries start their week on different days (day 1 is Sunday in America but in Great Britain day 1 is Monday).

You can do it without sub-queries, without `TO_CHAR` and without a `CASE` statement using `TRUNC` to find the start of the ISO week (which is always a Monday):

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE))
       + GREATEST(
           TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)) - TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE), 'IW') - 4,
           0
         ) AS last_business_day
FROM   DUAL
```

If you really want a `CASE` statement then:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE))
       - CASE TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)) - TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE), 'IW')
         WHEN 5 THEN 1
         WHEN 6 THEN 2
         ELSE 0
         END AS last_business_day
FROM   DUAL
```

Both those statements output (with the `NLS_DATE_FORAT` set to `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS (DY)`):

> | LAST_BUSINESS_DAY |
> | --- |
> | 2021-05-31 00:00:00 (MON) |

If you want to use your query and are only going to run it in territories where Sunday is the first day of the week then:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE))
       - CASE TO_CHAR(last_day(SYSDATE),'D') 
         WHEN '1' THEN 2
         WHEN '7' THEN 1
         ELSE 0
         END
       AS last_business_day
FROM  DAY;
```

If you run it on db<>fiddle (which has an `NLS_TERRITORY` of `UNITED KINGDOM`) then the output is:

> | LAST_BUSINESS_DAY |
> | --- |
> | 2021-05-29 00:00:00 (SAT) |

And, to compensate for the different days of the week, you would want to use:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE))
       - CASE TO_CHAR(last_day(SYSDATE),'D') 
         WHEN '6' THEN 1
         WHEN '7' THEN 2
         ELSE 0
         END
       AS last_business_day
FROM  dual;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7478e3ad4cc45b77803019121371ecbd)*